# Zeros of $\phi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $x<y$ be two zeros of $\phi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that there exists $\hat{x}\in(x,y)$, such that $\phi'(\hat{x})+\hat{x}\cdot\phi(\hat{x})=0$.

**My work so far:** I was able to show that the claim holds for the case $$\phi'(x)<0\land \phi'(y)>0 \tag{1}$$ or vice versa:

WLOG, assume (1) holds. Consider $\psi(z):=e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2}\cdot\phi(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$. We have that $\psi'(z)=e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2}\cdot z\cdot\phi(z)+e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2}\cdot \phi'(z)$ and hence $\psi'(x)<0, \psi'(y)>0$. We can now apply the intermediate value theorem and find that there exists $\hat{x}\in(x,y)$ which has the desired property, by definition of $\psi'$.

My problem now is to show this for the other cases that may arise or better yet, to reduce them to the above case.

Comment: You need to use Rolles thm instead. Your function equals zero at x,y

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you, this even makes the proof by cases unnecessary.